# Can't install cosmwasm-check

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I run the command:

```
cargo install cosmwasm-check
```

And i get this:

```
error: failed to compile `cosmwasm-check v1.2.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installF9zQyx`

Caused by:
  failed to download `addr2line v0.19.0`

Caused by:
  unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/home/xxvxrxx/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/addr2line-0.19.0/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  could not parse input as TOML

Caused by:
  TOML parse error at line 1, column 1
    |
  1 |
    | ^
  Unexpected ``
  Expected key or end of input
```

Can anyone tell me why is it doing that and how to fix it?

### Update

I copied the Toml file from github and now i get the same error but for the next crate in the folder

Comment: https://github.com/gimli-rs/addr2line/blob/master/Cargo.toml has content, including on the first line. Maybe you experienced some temporary glitch, such as network flakiness, or running out of disk/storage space?

Comment: It works for me, and I don't see any hidden characters in that file. I would delete the copy at `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gimli-rs/addr2line/master/Cargo.toml` and try again.